# Performance penalty when using std::queue versus std::deque?

Tags: c++, queue, deque

I'm wondering if there's any penalty of using std::queue versus std::deque.
It popped into my mind when playing with a toy thread pool and remembering an example of such pool was built around deque in Anthony Williams's concurrency book, although queue usage would have been clearer in that context.

A quick look at Visual Studio shows indirect calls to underlying deque, e.g.:

```
template<class... _Valty>
       void emplace(_Valty&&... _Val)
       {    // insert element at beginning
       c.emplace_back(_STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
       }
```

Is this indirect call optimized out by all compilers out there or is there a tiny penalty here?
I don't know what the standard says about performance for such container adapters. Deque's complexity is mentioned but nothing for queue - should be relative, of course, to the underlying container.

Comment: Most of the code involved would be inlined leading to no performance penalty.

Comment: You can answer your question all by yourself, by writing some simple benchmarking code.

Comment: **std::queue** is `a FIFO (first-in, first-out) data structure`, **std::deque** a `double-ended queue`. They differ in memory and methods, but for performance it's as @JoachimPileborg wrote.

Comment: @Youka To be more precise [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is a container *adapter* which uses [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) as its underlying container.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I see, so the there would be a single call to emplace_back instead of two function calls. Or even that emplace_back() is inlined? I'll generate the assembly code and see what is happening. Should have done that from the beginning, but didn't touch assembly for quite a while. Thanks.